# ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS ubuntu 17.10 i'm using this [manual](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Source). When executing the following command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro lunar -y` I get the following:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rosconsole: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
pcl_conversions: No definition of [libpcl-all-dev] for OS version []
camera_info_manager: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
catkin: No definition of [python-nose] for OS version []
class_loader: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
rosgraph: No definition of [python-mock] for OS version []
resource_retriever: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
webkit_dependency: No definition of [python-qt5-bindings-webkit] for OS version []
nodelet_topic_tools: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
rqt_graph: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rostest: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
rqt_console: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
qt_gui: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rospack: No definition of [python-coverage] for OS version []
depth_image_proc: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
pcl_ros: No definition of [libvtk-java] for OS version []
rqt_runtime_monitor: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
python_qt_binding: No definition of [python-qt5-bindings] for OS version []
laser_geometry: No definition of [python-numpy] for OS version []
image_proc: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
rviz: No definition of [yaml-cpp] for OS version []
collada_parser: No definition of [collada-dom] for OS version []
rqt_plot: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rqt_bag_plugins: No definition of [python-imaging] for OS version []
rqt_bag: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
actionlib: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
roslib: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
qt_gui_py_common: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
python_orocos_kdl: No definition of [python-sip] for OS version []
rosparam: No definition of [python-yaml] for OS version []
diagnostic_common_diagnostics: No definition of [python-psutil] for OS version []
roslaunch: No definition of [python-yaml] for OS version []
camera_calibration_parsers: No definition of [yaml-cpp] for OS version []
rqt_publisher: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
roswtf: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
geometric_shapes: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
stage_ros: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
rqt_robot_steering: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rqt_web: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
genpy: No definition of [python-yaml] for OS version []
roslisp: No definition of [boost] for OS version []  
message_filters: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
rosmake: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rosbag: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rqt_shell: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rostime: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
roscreate: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rqt_py_console: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rqt_topic: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
opencv3: No definition of [python-numpy] for OS version []
rospy: No definition of [python-yaml] for OS version []
rosunit: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
qt_dotgraph: No definition of [python-pygraphviz] for OS version []
rqt_top: No definition of [python-psutil] for OS version []
rqt_service_caller: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
cv_bridge: No definition of [python-numpy] for OS version []
rqt_rviz: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
rosbag_storage: No definition of [boost] for OS version []     
stage: No definition of [libjpeg] for OS version []
collada_urdf: No definition of [collada-dom] for OS version []
roslz4: No definition of [lz4] for OS version []
rqt_dep: No definition of [python-mock] for OS version []
rosmsg: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
random_numbers: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
rqt_pose_view: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rosclean: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
rqt_robot_monitor: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version []
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274615/error:-the-following-packages/stacks-could-not-have-their-rosdep-keys-resolved-to-system-dependencies/) by [Martelogie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31126/martelogie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Lunar is not supported on Ubuntu 17.10, that is probably why you are getting that error.

You can try to see whether `export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=ubuntu:17.04:zesty` works with `rosdep`, but it's still not supported.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-10-31**:
You can also override the OS in rosdep with the -o flag like `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -o ubuntu:zesty --rosdistro lunar -y`